# True random number generation with PHP in a raffle code

Tags: php

I have a raffle like program:
A user places x number of tokens, on an item. This gets recorded into the database as
    user_id, item_id, number_of_tokens

When the time comes to draw, I do the following:

```
$ballots = array();
$users = all users that placed at least one token on Item A.

foreach( $users as $user )
{
  $number_of_ballots = Get number of ballots this User placed on Item A
  for($i = 1; $i leq $number_of_ballots; $i++)
  {
    $ballots[] = $user->id;
  }
}
shuffle( $ballots );
$winner_user_id = mt_rand(0, count($ballots) -1 );
```

Now my questions are:

- Does this guarantee a random selection?
- Does a person that put 10 tokens on Item A have 10 times higher chance of winning than a person that put 1 token on item A?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good to me, but `mt_rand`, though better than rand, isn't perfect. You'd be better off using a true random number generator, such as http://www.random.org/. [Here's a little comparison](http://boallen.com/random-numbers.html) of them.

Additionally, if you are dealing with real money, random.org provides certificates of authenticity to verify the randomness of your selection.

Comment: Random.org it is. Looks very "true" and reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, to within the limits of the psuedo-random number generator. `mt_rand` is better than `rand`, but is still not truely random. The answer is really "close enough". Note that since you are randomly picking a winner from the set, you don't really need to `shuffle`.

Yes, a person with 10 tokens has a 10 times higher chance than one with 1 token.

Comment: great. Thanks. I'll have a look at random.org and http://boallen.com/random-numbers.html